# How to hide search bar in Web Broswer App Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Im new in programming of Android. I already set the url link that App need to show after start the App, so now I need help to find way or code to hide search bar of this project that I´m doing:

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
            }
        });

        loadMyUrl("google.com");


void loadMyUrl(String url){
        boolean matchUrl = Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches();
        if(matchUrl){
            webView.loadUrl(url);
        }else{
            webView.loadUrl("google.com/search?q="+url);
        }

    }
```

Many thanks in advance

Please help me to find the code to hide bar of this project

Comment: what seachbar you're talking about? app bar or website's serach bar?